# Java questions CSV/batch/js in jar

Tags: java, csv, batch-file

i have multiple questions here that may sound annoying...

1. What is batch processing in java is it related to .bat files and how to write batch files?
2. How to read CSV files in java? and what are CSV Files how do we clarify which value depicts which thing?
3. can we include js files in jar ? if yes then how ?
4. how to compile a java file from command prompt and mention the jar used by it.

Comment: 2. Check out the various OpenSource solutions for processing CSV: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is batch processing in java is it related to .bat files and how to write batch files?

Batch Processing is not Java specific. It is explained pretty well in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing)

> Batch processing is execution of a series of programs ("jobs") on a computer without manual intervention.
>
> Batch jobs are set up so they can be run to completion without manual intervention, so all input data is preselected through scripts or command-line parameters. This is in contrast to "online" or interactive programs which prompt the user for such input. A program takes a set of data files as input, processes the data, and produces a set of output data files. This operating environment is termed as "batch processing" because the input data are collected into batches of files and are processed in batches by the program.

There are different ways to implement batch processing in Java, but I guess the most powerful library available is [Spring Batch](http://static.springframework.org/spring-batch) (but it has a steep learning curve). Batch processing is only marginally related to [windows .bat batch files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

> 2) How to read CSV files in java? and what are CSV Files how do we clarify which value depicts which thing?

When dealing with CSV (or other structured data, like XML, JSON or database contents), you usually want to map the data to Java objects, so you need a library that does Object mapping. For CSV, [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is such a library (see this section on [Java bean mapping](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration)).

> 3) can we include js files in jar ? if yes then how ?

see [gdj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395939/java-questions-csv-batch-js-in-jar/4395978#4395978). You can put anything in a jar, but resources in a jar will not be available as `File` objects, only as `InputStream` using the [Class.getResourceAsStream(name)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(name)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) methods

Comment: i am packaging the js in jar and want its data any alternative to java6 classes in java5?

Comment: these methods have been around for ages. they are available in Java 1.5 and earlier versions as well: [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

1. processing a lot of data at once
2. CSV is comma-separated values, a file format. try the [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library
3. yes but you can only read them from Java code (you can't tell Apache to serve them directly over HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

1. Batch processing is not a Java specific term. Whenever you perform an action on a group of objects/files, we can term it as batch processing. ".bat" files are Windows equivalent of shell scripts. They do not have any connection to Java or batch processing in Java.
2. CSV are "Comma Separated Values" i.e each column in a line of the file is delimted by "comma". You can read CSV files using normal `FileReader` and then using `StringTokenizer` to parse through each line.
3. I guess we could include anything in a Jar file. I don't see how it is going to prevent that.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend manual parsing of CSV files. As soon as you got those special values, you are screwed :(

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no direct relationship between java and bat. Batch files are files written in windows shell language. Sometimes we use bat files to run our java programs on windows. In this case batch file typically is used to generate the java command line like

   java -cp THE-CLASSPATH com.mycompany.Main arg1 arg2
2. You can read CSV file as a regular text file and then split it using `String.split()` method. Alternatively you can use one of available open source CSV parsers, e.g. from jakarta: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html
3. JAR file is just a ZIP file. You can include everything into ZIP including js. How to do this? It depends on how do you create jar file at all. If for example you are using ant script just include `*.js` into the `include` pattern.

If you need more specific answer ask more specific question.